# How to write true color random (java)

Tags: java, random, colors, window, paint

This is my code:

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random; 
import javax.swing.*
public class GraphsPaneTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myFrame window = new myFrame();
    }
}
```

---

```
class myFrame extends JFrame {
    public myFrame() {
        myPanel panel = new myPanel();
        Container cont = getContentPane();
        cont.add(panel);
        setBounds(100,100,500,500);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

```
class myPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
        super.paintComponent(gr); 
        Random ab = new Random(); 
        colors={Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.ORANGE, Color.PINK}; //Here an error
        int colorsThis = ab.nextInt(colors[colorThis]); //Here an error
        gr.setColor(Color.RED); //I try it, but it does't work //And here an error
        int a=1;
        while (a<10) {
            Random b = new Random(); 
            gr.fillRect(b.nextInt(900+1),b.nextInt(900+1), b.nextInt(50+1), b.nextInt(50+1)); 
            a++; 
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to create some code which has square which has a random color at a random coordinate with random bounds. I have an error. Please help. I know my English is very bad.

Comment: colors cannot be resolved to a variable?

Comment: @Timlevski-Anthany In Java you have to declare a variable to give it an explicit type before you can use it.  You have not done this with `colors`.

Comment: `Color[] colors = {Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.ORANGE, Color.PINK};`

Comment: @Campino thanks you:3.. this works

Comment: @azurefrog i see now, sorry i'm beginner:D

Comment: No problem! Feel free to mark my answer as the accepted one if it helped you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will generate a truly random colour rather than a predefined colour in an array:

```
public Color randomColor() {
        Random r = new Random();
        float red, green, blue;
        red = r.nextFloat();
        green = r.nextFloat();
        blue = r.nextFloat();
        return new Color(red, green, blue);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the type of the array. In Java, you have to declare the variable before using it. In this case the

*<strike>colors = {...};</strike>*

you have to define type of the array ->

type [ ] colors = {...};

try this for random colors

int R = (int)(Math.random( )*256);
int G = (int)(Math.random( )*256);
int B = (int)(Math.random( )*256);
Color randomColor = new Color(R, G, B);